# Run python on Cygwin using batch file

Tags: python, windows, bash

I would like to know how to create  a batch file to execute Python on Cygwin please

Tried 2 methods

Method 1:

```
cd c:\cygwin64\bin

bash --login -i

python /home/xxxxx/snmptest.py
```

Method 2:

```
cd c:\cygwin64\bin

bash --login -i

/bin/bash.exe /home/xxxxx/snmp.sh
```

The bash file contains

```
#!/bin/bash
python /home/xxxxx/snmptest.py
```

Both fails to run the Python script i.e. just opens the Cygwin window.

In Method 2, I could successfully execute the bash file on Cygwin and get the python script running.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I am after please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file that I run on Windows to execute a shell script named "my_shell_command" that runs in cygwin:

```
export HOME="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/$USERNAME"
export PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
. .bash_profile

dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
dir="C:${dir#/cygdrive/c}"

my_shell_command

if (( $? == 0 ))
then
    sleep 2
else
    echo "" >&2
    echo "Hit \"Enter\" when done reading the above error/warning messages." >&2
    read resp
fi
```

It is stored on my desktop in a file named "my_shell_command.bash" and in Windows I have the "bash" extension set to "Open With" bash.exe so I can just double click on the batch script to execute my shell script from Windows.

Hopefully that's all you'll need to modify it to work for you.